# How to show from database to Django Data Field?

Tags: django, widget, datafield

I select date using DateField and insert date value using this.

```
 form = DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES))
```

and then, I want to show selected value using DateField(form) in HTML from database

```
 (when create profileForm())
 Birth: selectbox(------), selectbox(------), selectbox(------) 
 : solved

 (if edit profile page using profileForm())
  Birth: selectbox(1987) selectbox(10) selectbox(25)
 -> I want it
```

How to insert value into DataField, and show selectDateWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not too clear.

You should post more information from you `forms.py` and your `views.py`. Are you using `forms.Form` or `forms.ModelForm`?

Either way I think your question is about using `initial` data in your form.

Note that this field in particular accepts a python `datetime` object (see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values
Use is like this:

```
f = ContactForm(initial={'my_date_field': datetime.datetime.now()})
```

If you are using `ModelForm` is is like this:

```
f = ContactForm(instance=Contact.objects.get(pk=1))
```

This will initialise all the values from the models (and thus database).

Comment: Thank's your advice. problem is solved. I make tuple. YEARS={'a','b','c','d','e'...) and ~~Field(label='~', widget='~', choices=YEARS)